# Devise Unpermitted parameters Error + Sample Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and Devise 3.2.2. I'm getting this error, `Unpermitted parameters: password_confirmation`, that is addressed many times on this site, as well as in the Devise wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

I can't get anything to work. Hopefully this is not a bug in the framework.

Here is a sample project: https://github.com/rdetert/devisetest

Comment: Have you got any details of how you've been using Devise & how you've installed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample app you have

```
class Coaches::RegistrationsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

You should have

```
class Coaches::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

That is, your controller needs to inherit from `Devise::RegistrationsController`

Comment: OMG, you sir, are a legend.